# Group by count possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables:

```
1.customer (contains customers)
2.customer_order (contains orders)
```

I want to know this:

```
no. of customers with 0 orders
no. of customers with 1 order
no. of customers with 2 orders
etc
```

i have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(co.id)
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN customer_order co
ON c.id=co.id_customer
GROUP BY ??? ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This gives the amount of orders per customer

```
SELECT co.id Customer, COUNT(*) Orders
FROM customer_order co  
GROUP BY co.id_customer;
```

Now use that as a table, and query it

```
SELECT Orders, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT co.id Customer, COUNT(*) Orders
  FROM customer_order co  
  GROUP BY co.id_customer;
)
GROUP BY Orders
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT cnt, count(*) FROM (SELECT c.id, count(*) cnt FROM customer c 
                      LEFT JOIN customer_order co ON c.id=co.id_customer 
                      GROUP BY c.id) GROUP BY cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT count(*), order_count
FROM (
  SELECT c.id, count(*) AS order_count
  FROM customer c, customer_order co
  WHERE c.id = co.id_customer
  GROUP BY c.id
) as A
GROUP BY order_count
```

And [here's an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84bad/1) with the working query and test data.

Comment: What is this `order_count` your outer query refers to? You need to alias a column in your inner query to thsi.

Comment: @DanielGimenez Unsure what happened to my fiddle, seems locked. Came up with the query some quarter of an hour ago... worked out the fiddle later on to check syntax works on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You Should have to group by order so you can get the no. of customer on each order